# How do I convert 1 word (2 bytes) to a float in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I'm using Node-RED to read input from a Modbus server more specifically the MOXA ioLogik E2262 and the manual for the controller says if you use *Function 4* from the modbus commands to read an analogue signal, the data type returned will be "1 word".

So I assume the *Modbus Flex Getter node* should be outputting "1 word"/ "2 bytes". I'm trying to read a temperature value so I'd like it to be a float value. Looking at the Modbus response though,I'm getting "65535" and I can't figure out what this is.

Can someone please help me with this ?
[image: Modbus/TCP Address Mappings]

[image: Node-RED flow]

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70313089/edit) the question to give an example of the input data and if there data is little or big endian. Also are you sure it's a floating point number and just just an integer value that you need to divide by 100?

Comment: This node-red forum post looks like it might help (not exactly your problem, but lots of discussion around type coercion) [Convert modbus float array register to value](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/convert-modbus-float-array-register-to-value/26303/4)

Comment: @hardillb I've edited my question and added more information.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for the referral. I added that buffer-parser to my flow but when I try to use it, it says "Error: data is not an array or a buffer"

Comment: I think you need to go read the docs about your Modbus device some more, If it is returning a 2 byte value for an analogue input then it is going to be a scaling value for a given range. e.g. if the reading is between 0 degrees and 100 degrees then you divide 100 by the int value of the 2 bytes represents. 2bytes is not enough information for normal float value.

Comment: 65535 is 0xff 0xff this the maximum value possible to be represented by 2 bytes and most likely signifies an error.

Answer (score -1):

```
var msg0 = {payload:(msg.payload[1]<<16)+msg.payload[0]}
return msg0;
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question